# RTL150.BPL not found

Tags: delphi, exec, vcl

i have this problem: i compile and run application and all work in mine computer. When i try to run same application in other computer, i have error about rtl150.bpl not found.
I have searched on internet and all response that i have had tell me to verify if in PROJECT->OPTION->PACKAGES is checked: "BUILD WITH RUNTIME PACKAGE".
It is checked, i compile project but i have same every error. I have saw too that executable of application is very small for example: 186 KB, when usually it was about 2000 KB. 
I use delphi xe and not know as i need to do for solve it.
Please, someone can help me to solve this problem?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Just uncheck the "BUILD WITH RUNTIME PACKAGE" checkbox to solve your problem.

Answer (score 12):

If you build with packages you must distribute the packages (.BPL files) your application uses.

**If you don't build with runtime packages you won't get this error.**

The list of packages you must distribute is semi-colon delimited list next to the check box for Build with run time packages in the project options.

[image: Project Options Dialog]

The Size of an Executable will drop when building with Runtime packages.    That is because the code is now in the BPL/Package.   But that means your application now needs these additional files.   Think of a Package as a specialized DLL that has been renamed.

Comment: @Danny.  Packages are specific to a version of Delphi.    Packages are separate files and are not included in your application.